# How much, if any, does the choice of host language affect OpenCL performance?

Tags: c#, c++, performance, parallel-processing, opencl

Does the choice of host language make a difference when using OpenCL? If so, are there any guidelines for how to choose the host language?

For example, I am going to create a framework for training big neural networks on big data sets, using OpenCL. I have a choice of which host language to use, say either C++ or C#. Assuming that I make the most effective use of OpenCL and that most of the computation is happening within the OpenCL kernels, will my choice of host language make any difference?

Comment: If the kernel does all the heavy work, then it doesn't matter what language you write the host in. It would matter if you did a lot of calls between managed code (your C# host) and unmanaged code (the OpenCL API), because frequent marshaling and object pinning typically put some burden on the CLR, but this would be a very unusual and very inefficient usage of OpenCL anyway. There is no reason to believe that copying buffers to your GPU memory is any slower in C# than it is in C++ (and I would trust a library to use the `Marshal` class which employs internal calls of the CLR)

Comment: @Addy questions asking "Which is better" are generally off topic here before they are too subjective and opinionated. Questions on SE should not have opinions for answers. I've rewritten the question to be less subjective but still get the basic idea across; please feel free to edit further if you think I missed your point.

Comment: @AnupRawka, please don't add "thanks" to a post. In fact, you should be [removing them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2950/213671).

Answer (score 1):

There is no performance difference between writting the program in C++ or C#, because the code you write is the same in both lanugages (The OpenCL code syntax). This code is then compiled at run time by your opencl runtime (To apply performance optimizations specific for your device). And then loaded to the device(GPU).

Comment: Thanks for answer! I understand that the GPU computation speed is identical, but what I'm asking is specifically how much can the host application influence the performance of OpenCL, i.e. the speed of preparation of data and calling the OpenCL functions. With enough GPU computation happening, this should be completely negligible, right?

Comment: Right. As long as you keep the command queue(s) non-empty, the host language does not matter.